# WooCommerce - Remove automaticly added membership product if user remove regular product from cart

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I managed to add a product if a user is the first buyer. But when what I want to achieve is when a user deletes that product, automatically gift or membership product will be deleted.
I was using woocommerce_cart_item_removed, but with no luck. Probably I'm missing something but I don't know what.
If someone wants to help me, I will be more then thankful

```
/*
 * This function will check if customer has purchased any product.
 */
function monsalo_has_bought() {

    $count = 0;
    $bought = false;

    if(!get_current_user_id()) {
        return false;
    }

    // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => array('wc-completed', 'wc-in-progress', 'in-progress') // Only orders with status "completed" & "In  Progress"
    ) );

    // Going through each current customer orders
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
        $count++;
    }

    // return "true" when customer has already one order
    if ( $count > 0 ) {
        $bought = true;
    }
    return $bought;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_membership_product_to_cart', 10, 2 );
/*
* Automatically adding the product to the cart.
*/
function add_membership_product_to_cart( $item_key, $product_id ) {
    // Get all member plans
    $plans = wc_memberships_get_membership_plans();

    $free_product_id = 14275;  // Product Id of the free product which will get added to cart
    if ( !monsalo_has_bought() || !wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( get_current_user_id(), $plan )) {
        $found      = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->get_id() == $free_product_id )
                    $found = true;

            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
        }
    }
}



/*
  * WITH THIS CODE I'm HAVING THE PROBLEM
  */

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'remove_membership_from_cart', 10, 2 );
function remove_membership_from_cart() {
    $free_product_id = 14275;
    if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) < 1 ) {
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $_product = $values['data'];
            if ( $_product->get_id() == $free_product_id )
                $found = true;
                WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $free_product_id );
        }
    }
}
```

### MY SOLUTION

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'remove_membership_from_cart', 10, 2 );
function remove_membership_from_cart() {
    $free_product_id = 14275;
    if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) === 1 ) {
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $_product = $values['data'];
            if ( $_product->get_id() == $free_product_id )
                $found = true;
                $cartId = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $free_product_id );
                $cartItemKey = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $cartId );
                WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cartItemKey );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `woocommerce_remove_cart_item` [action](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1125)?

Comment: First the hook is missing from your 2nd function.… Now Don't use the method `remove_cart_item()` with `woocommerce_cart_item_removed`  and `woocommerce_remove_cart_item` hooks, as both hooks are included in this method source code, so you are making an infinite loop. Instead try to use `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` action hook for example.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec thank you for your time. I forgot to copy that action here, so code is updated now.
And about `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` it's same result, item is not deleted

Comment: @MaxYudin Nope, same result.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec it's working with `template_redirect`, but i need to update a code a little bit more. I will update my Question